# Printer/job list in 17.04 Gnome session

Tags: unity, gnome, printing

I've recently upgraded to 17.04 and started using Gnome instead of Unity. When I send something to the printer I get a quick notification but I miss the printers indicator I used to have in Unity (and other systems). It allowed me to quickly view the active printer/job list and cancel them if I wanted. Also, I miss the "Send test page" option in the printer setup.

Is there a replacement for this?

TIA

Fernando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the [Printers Shell Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1218/printers/). It's not quite the same, but it seems OK.